# Postfix configuration;

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I cofigure a postfix/dovecot. I'm using default dovecot certificate for testing. but when i try to restart service integrity fail. But I'm not sure where is the problem.
I followed [DigitalOcean guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin). Where the problem, what parameter must be changed? Thanks in advance!

```
/usr/lib/postfix/post-install: Error: "no smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem         smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem smtpd_use_tls=yes smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes" should be "no" or an absolute path name.
postfix/postfix-script: warning: unable to create missing queue directories
postfix/postfix-script: fatal: Postfix integrity check failed!
```

Comment: `no smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem` ---> maybe postfix can't find the certificate. Permission issue maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error was a blank space at beginning the line and I can't see it in nano editor.
Thanks.